# I keep getting a TypeError

Tags: python, typeerror

I am trying to make a program that determines if a number is odd or even.
The program is made in Python and it takes input from the user.

A program that takes a number and tells the user if it is odd or even

```
def OddorEven():
    try:
        number = input("Enter a number: ")
        int(number)
        oddoreven == number % 2
        if oddoreven == 0:
            print("Your number is an even number")
        else:
            print("Your numbe is an odd number")
        except:
            print("You did not enter a number!")
            OddorEven()

OddorEven()
```

> An exception has occurred: NameError
>   name 'oddoreven' is not defined
>     File "C:\Users\istif\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\Even.py", line 4, in 
>       oddoreven == number % 2

Comment: `=` and `==` is not the same... and this is not a TypeError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert the number in int then you should store in some variable.

number = int(number)
 then do
Oddoreven= number%2
And use = assignment sign not comparison == sign
Because if u don't store it in another variable it will not be casted to int and then it will be treated as string only that's why you are getting typeerror

Comment: If it helps you then you can accept the answer so that it can help others also

Answer (score 0):

**Code -**

```
def OddorEven():
    try:
        number = input("Enter a number: ")
        number = int(number) #you have to assign the conversion to the variable again.
        oddoreven = number % 2 #remember = and == are not same. == is for comparison
        if oddoreven == 0:
            print("Your number is an even number")
        else:
            print("Your number is an odd number")
    except:
        print("You did not enter a number!")
        OddorEven()

OddorEven()
```

**Two mistakes -**

1. you have to assign the conversion to the variable
2. `=` and `==` are not same. [Quick google search would help you better in detail](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-operator-python/)